# Reciving FCM Push notiification multiple times in web browser

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using FCM for push notification in the web. I'm sending push notification one time, but I'm receiving same notification multiple time. I searched a lot on internet, but did not found any solution.

please help me.

here is my code.

```
   firebase.messaging().onMessage(function(notificationPayload) {
   alert('received push notification);
   });
```

I'm using firebase bower with version ^5.5.9

I have also used angularfire for chat application here is the link (https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html)

Comment: Show us your code that sends notifications... are you using a loop? do you have multiple tokens for a same device ?

Comment: there is no loop used. also confirmed that there is a single token for the device.for sending push notification i have used firebase console

Comment: Hello @RanjitRathod, any findings on your ques? Im actually facing this too

Comment: Did anyone found the solution for this query?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using React then make sure that your messages or notifications render only when the component mounts and unmounts.

```
useEffect(()=>{

    navigator.serviceWorker.addEventListener("message", (message) => {
       
    })
return () => console.log('unmounting...');

},[])
```